# Springfox displays duplicate models in the swagger ui

Tags: spring-rest, springfox

I have two models Package and File. Both are JPA entities that are annotated with @ApiModel. Also there is a ManyToMany relationship between them.

There are other classes that reference Package and File though.

I already added a value to the @ApiModel annotation.

```
@ApiModel(value = "the package")
public class Package {

   @ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "file_package",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "file_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "package_id")
    )
    @ApiModelProperty(name = "The list of files")
    private List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

In the swagger ui (localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/), the Package model appears 3 times as:

Package
Package_1
Package_2
Package_3

The weird part is that if I create a REST controller that uses Package or File I get this error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous models equality when conditions is empty.
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.checkCondition(ApiModelReader.java:655)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.mergeConditions(ApiModelReader.java:537)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.mergeModelBranch(ApiModelReader.java:236)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.read(ApiModelReader.java:149)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiListingScanner.scan(ApiListingScanner.java:144)

Comment: Are you using version 3.0.0.SNAPSHOT by any chance? See https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2345

Answer (score 0):

Still, an open issue

Related to  spring data-rest. Hope for fix in next release.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3014?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container